# wish to more simply multiply a 2D rectangular array by a 1D constant vector

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix-multiplication

I have the cosine of 90 through -90 in steps of 1 in an array called
latcos:

```
lat=range(90,-91,-1)

latcos=numpy.cos(numpy.deg2rad(lat))

rect_array=numpy.zeros(181,361)

#comment: not shown here but rect_array gets assigned some interesting values.
```

I wish to multiply every column (contains 181 elements) of rect_array element by element by latcos, and do this for each of the 381 columns.

ipython likes this syntax for one single column

```
new_partial_rect_array=latcos*rect_array[0:,0]
```

and likes this syntax to do the entire array

```
for i in range(361): New_rect_array[0:,i]=latcos*rect_array[0:,i]
```

but python doesn't like

```
New_rect_array=latcos*rect_array
```

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (181,) (181,361)

There must be a simpler way to do this later multiplication on the entire rectangular matrix (each column) without the for statement, but I'm not familiar enough with python yet to know how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: wat? you're multiplying an array of zeroes with a scalar number?

Comment: No, that is just to illustrate the size of the array - the real use fills it with values.

Comment: Could you provide the code you're really using (except for what ever generates the "interesting values"), as your current example has syntax errors and wrong arguments to functions etc.

Comment: check out `numpy` and `broadcasting`.

Comment: OK - I've fixed the syntax errors, perhaps that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - quite simple, sort of:

```
numpy.transpose(numpy.transpose(rect_array) * latcos)
```

I thought I could get away with just one transpose, but seems I need both of them.